# How can you change the parameterless constructor of an Entity Framework 6 database-first generated class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

On previous versions of EF (4, 5) I had the following extension to my `User` class:

```
public partial class User {
    public User()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

But on EF6, the code generation creates a class with an already defined default parameterless constructor, and as such I get the following compile-time error:

> Type 'Core.Models.User' already defines a member called 'User' with the same parameter types

How can I ensure the initialization of the `DateCreated` value on construction with EF6 database-first?
More generally: how can I create a custom parameterless constructor in EF6 *generated classes?

**EDIT:** Here's a reduced version of the autogenerated class for reference:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Core.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
            this.UserOpenIDs = new HashSet<UserOpenID>();
            this.Flags = new HashSet<Flag>();
            this.AwardedMedals = new HashSet<AwardedMedal>();
        }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string RealName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserOpenID> UserOpenIDs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Flag> Flags { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AwardedMedal> AwardedMedals { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement a 2nd parameterless constructor `User()`, because there is already one in the auto-generated class.

Hence, you have only 2 options to resolve this issue:

1. Inherit from the original class `User` (see below).
2. Modify the [T4-template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) so the parameterless constructor is generated with the extra code `DateCreated = DateTime.Now;` you want to add. That will generate the extra code each time you refresh your data model from the database.

If you want to choose **option 1,** do it as shown below:

```
public class myUser: User 
{
    public myUser(): base()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

**N.B.:** You will have to use type casts in order to support your class myUser.